# Android to Blackberry Runtime

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-10

I have a Android app that was made with Java - can I port this to Blackberry 10? Someone told me no, but just wanted to check here.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you compile a libraty (a Java one) you can import it in a new Android project - how does that sound?

Comment: Disagree with off-topic rating - primarily because BB does provide tools to port android apps to its platform, largely as-is.  I was preparing an answer for this when I realized I was blocked from replying.

Comment: In any case, here's where to start if yo uwant to port your android app to bb and publish it in blackberry world:
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/

Answer (score 1):

BlackBerry 10 can run (some) Android application repackaged as bar applications. If you're talking about it, you'll have to know that some API are not compatible (no Google Maps API, no native code allowed, for example). You can go [there](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/) and check your application compatibility.

If you're talking about developing a "pure" BlackBerry 10 application, starting with your Android Java sources, you will need to rewrite all of it in C++. BlackBerry 10 doesn't run Java code, excepted repackaged Android applications.